# Confusion with ' operator and bracketing where (v')*v becomes Ac_mul_B despite overloading

Tags: julia

I am playing around with the idea of CoVectors in Julia and am getting some behaviour I didn't expect from the parser/compiler. I have defined a new `CoVector` type that is the `ctranspose` of any vector, and is just a simple decoration:

```
type CoVector{T<:AbstractVector}
    v::T
end
```

They can be created (and uncreated) with `'` using `ctranspose`:

```
import Base.ctranspose

function CoVector(T::DataType,d::Integer=0)
    return CoVector(Array(T,d))
end

function Base.ctranspose(cv::CoVector)
    return cv.v
end

function Base.ctranspose(v::AbstractVector)
    return CoVector(v)
end

function Base.ctranspose(v::Vector) # this is already specialized in Base
    return CoVector(v)
end
```

Next I want to define a simple dot product

```
function *(x::CoVector,y::AbstractVector)
    return dot(x.v,y)
end
```

Which can work fine for:

```
v = [1,2,3]
cv = v'
cv*v
```

returns `14`, and `cv` is a `CoVector`. But if I do

```
(v') * v
```

I get something different! In this case it is a single element array containing `14`. How come parenthesis doesn't work how I expect?

In the end we see the expression gets expanded to `Ac_mul_B` which defaults to `[dot(A,B)]` and it seems that this interpretation is defined at the "operator" level.

Is this expected behaviour? **Can Julia completely ignore my bracketing and change the expression as it wants?** In Julia I like that I can override things in Base but is it also possible to make self-consistent changes to how operators are applied? I see the expression doesn't have head `call` but `Symbol call`... does this change in Julia 0.4? (I read somewhere that `call` is becoming more universal).

I guess I can fix the problem by redefining `Ac_mul_B` but I was very surprised that it was called at all, given my above definitions.

Comment: You can do `@eval(v')*v` to force conversion to `CoVector` before `*` is interpreted, but I don't know if that helps.  Just speculation on my part, but it seems that the dispatch for `*` is complicated because it's being interpreted as matrix multiplication before your redefined `ctranspose` operation is applied.  Then Julia is quite sensibly saying `Ac_mul_B` for a pair of vectors is `[dot(A,B)]`.  I (so far) lack sophistication in Julia's wonderful typing system, so I can't offer much more than that.

Comment: Please, please, please don't use eval for things like this. The parser doesn't pay attention to parens. I would just do the transpose on a separate line.

Comment: No it doesn't look like dispatch to me.  `(v')*v` is not the same as `ctranspose(v)*v`.  Adding the appropriate analog for `transpose(cv::CoVector)` does not help either.  So at least in this situation `'` seems not to be the same as `ctranspose`.

Comment: @StefanKarpinski thanks for the correction to my comment.  It's a rookie mistake (I am a rookie after all).  As I realized later, I should have said `ctranspose(v)`.  Is the correct protocol for me to correct that comment, or to leave it as is and rely on your comment to keep things straight.  I like to do things properly, so I appreciate any corrections and advice.

Comment: OK interesting @Mike-Satteson... but I'm still left with a couple questions. First, the [docs](http://julia.readthedocs.org/en/latest/manual/functions/) explicitly state that you control the use of `'` by setting the `ctranspose` function, as if it was a kind of alias/syntactic sugar, so if that is not true perhaps that could be clarified. I feel something funny is happening with `Symbol call` as opposed to `call`, which isn't documented.

Comment: @StefanKarpinski This is also an (unusual) feature that isn't in the docs, that I saw. In other languages like C++ I would assume using brackets or multiple lines with a temporary (appropriately typed, and that may be optimized away by the compiler) is guaranteed to give the same result.

Comment: I've been poking through some of the code to see why `'` may not be equivalent to `ctranspose` and see notes in [abstractarray.jl](https://github.com/JuliaLang/juli/blob/86141889f9403ac1acee2ea14d7a683fb0397434/base/abstractarray.jl) that _"ctranspose not implemented for $(typeof(a))....'_ Perhaps that unimplemented behavior accounts for what you're seeing.

Comment: As far as I can tell, [here](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/aabd23bce01d2b582118c3fdf525e2d481a9c210/src/julia-syntax.scm#L2050) is where `'` is turned into `ctranspose`.  I'm not a lisp person and this is about as deeply as I've dived into Julia's inner workings, so I may not be able to offer much more on this question.

Comment: I keep picking at this in my noobish way.  It's a learning experience.  Alas I have no more time, but I could not resist one last thing.  `dump(:(v' * v))` and `dump(:(ctranspose(v) * v))` show some interesting differences.  If I were more knowledgeable or had the time just now to gain the right knowledge, these slight differences might form the basis for an answer to this question.

Comment: @MikeSatteson Thanks! There is that for the "simple" case but then there is all the stuff about `expand-transposed-op` that is used for `'*` and similar that call directly `Ac_mul_B`. So if you're playing tricky games like I am you need to make sure `Ac_mul_B` and transpose/multiply over multiple lines gives consistent results (it seems this was done as a partial optimization - ideally Julia should do full delayed matrix evaluation like Armidillo using the type system to optimize entire expressions but I can't figure out how to automatically cast expressions back to arrays (staged functions?))